# What is the proper way to initialize redis cluster

Tags: phpredis

On the docs it does not outline what the best practices are - if someone has let's say 8 redis nodes, would you initialize phpredis with a server array containing all 8 nodes?

From my understanding, the client will iterate over all the nodes given that it cannot connect on the first one.

Answer (score 0):

phpredis with redis cluster does not evenly spread load across the array of servers, it will  favor the first few in the array almost all the time.

In order to combat this, use shuffle on the array of servers and you will see a more evenly spread load.